# Possible to return to the 3 vertical Mail.app columns?

Tags: macos, mail.app

I tried this option, and now sit with the folders on the left in Apple Mail on my Mac, then vertical preview pane (fine), and my full view message pane disappeared.  No amount of 'handle pulling' from
 the right has restored the view.

I have checked preferences in Mail, and changed between the classic & other layouts to no avail.  HELP.

I really want to return to the 3 vertical columns (folders, preview, and full view), in that order.  Thanks.

Comment: I assume that you are talking about the built in mail client? Never heard of MacMail so just curious.

Comment: If that is so I just tried to minimize the full message view all to the right. Making the messages list (what I think you refer to as 'vertical preview pane'). After that I had problems dragging it back out of the side. The reason for the problem getting it to show is that it require a certain width in order to show. As long as you have a <-| handle you should be able to drag it out far.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I have repeatedly tried to pull back on the handle, no luck.  I can resize all the other panes no problem though.  When you open a message, it opens in a completely new window, as if it has split off from the rest, and had to be closed off separate as well. It is very frustrating. Will keep trying. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Hoshts is correct—I've made a recording showing what it will look like when you "resize" the invisible column:

[image: gif]

Comment: Thanks for showing, still struggling, see previous reply. No problem resizing the others. Full view seems to have split off from the rest of the panes. Thanks.

Comment: @JBD do you ever see the cursor with the one arrow pointing left?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem in Mail 10.2 (3259) on macOS 10.12.2 Sierra.  The <-| resize handle was not always present, but toggling to Classic view and back again may have affected that.  More importantly, when dragging that handle to the left from the extreme right side of the window, there is no visible effect until moving it a certain distance.  For me it was about half the width of the window.  When reaching that point, the pane appears at that width and follows the drag to the left, but disappears if moved back to the right past that same point.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Preferences and open the Viewing tab. There you will see a checkbox that says ‘Use classic layout’. Uncheck that box. You will now have to drag the message preview pane resize bar from the extreme right as you need.